# only 1 of mulitiple json arrays going into mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

### Hi.

The Json file has 13 arrays but I have only display 2 arrays for this question (structurally its all the same).

The PHP(A) script is only parsing 1 of the 2 Json arrays into the MySQL DB...

I have another PHP(B) test script that "echo's" the exact same Json file to screen and displays the 2 "arrays"... i know this is because of the way i have written the $variable output for each array in PHP(B) and it not a "foreach" loop. (so direct from the URL works and will output to screen)

But i cant seem to apply the same "logic" to the PHP(A) script into the DB, you can also see some "commented out" script I tried to apply but didn't work...

so where am i going wrong with the PHP(A) script... any help appreciated...

### Json script

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "sport_key": "soccer_epl",
      "sport_nice": "EPL",
      "teams": [
        "Arsenal",
        "Fulham"
      ],
      "commence_time": 1538910000,
      "home_team": "Fulham",
      "sites": [
        {
          "site_key": "unibet",
          "site_nice": "Unibet",
          "last_update": 1538860569,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.6,
              5.37,
              4.67
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "crownbet",
          "site_nice": "CrownBet",
          "last_update": 1538860546,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.59,
              4.9,
              4.4
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "beteasy",
          "site_nice": "Bet Easy",
          "last_update": 1538860572,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.59,
              4.9,
              4.4
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "sportsbet",
          "site_nice": "SportsBet",
          "last_update": 1538860570,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.57,
              5,
              4.5
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "betfair",
          "site_nice": "Betfair",
          "last_update": 1538860581,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.64,
              5.6,
              4.6
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "neds",
          "site_nice": "Neds",
          "last_update": 1538860571,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.62,
              5,
              1.62
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "ladbrokes",
          "site_nice": "Ladbrokes",
          "last_update": 1538860575,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.6,
              5,
              4.33
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "tab",
          "site_nice": "TAB",
          "last_update": 1538860547,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.6,
              5,
              4.2
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "ubet",
          "site_nice": "UBet",
          "last_update": 1538860577,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.65,
              4.5,
              4.2
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "sites_count": 9
    },
    {
      "sport_key": "soccer_epl",
      "sport_nice": "EPL",
      "teams": [
        "Chelsea",
        "Southampton"
      ],
      "commence_time": 1538918100,
      "home_team": "Southampton",
      "sites": [
        {
          "site_key": "unibet",
          "site_nice": "Unibet",
          "last_update": 1538860569,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.65,
              5.9,
              4
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "crownbet",
          "site_nice": "CrownBet",
          "last_update": 1538860546,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.62,
              5.5,
              3.85
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "beteasy",
          "site_nice": "Bet Easy",
          "last_update": 1538860572,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.62,
              5.5,
              3.85
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "sportsbet",
          "site_nice": "SportsBet",
          "last_update": 1538860570,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.57,
              5.5,
              4
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "betfair",
          "site_nice": "Betfair",
          "last_update": 1538860581,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.66,
              6.2,
              4.2
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "neds",
          "site_nice": "Neds",
          "last_update": 1538860571,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.62,
              5.75,
              1.62
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "ladbrokes",
          "site_nice": "Ladbrokes",
          "last_update": 1538860575,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.62,
              5.25,
              3.9
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "tab",
          "site_nice": "TAB",
          "last_update": 1538860547,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.6,
              5.5,
              3.8
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "site_key": "ubet",
          "site_nice": "UBet",
          "last_update": 1538860577,
          "odds": {
            "h2h": [
              1.62,
              5.5,
              3.8
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "sites_count": 9
    }
  ]
}
```

## PHP(A) script

```
<?php

    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "web";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "football";
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Error in Connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

    $st = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO epl_odds(sport_nice, team1, team2, commence_time, home_team, site_nice, home, draw, away) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, 'sssssssss', $sport_nice, $team1, $team2, $commence_time, $home_team, $site_nice, $home, $draw, $away);

    $filename = 'json.json';
    $json = file_get_contents($filename);

    $data = json_decode($json, true);


    foreach ($data as $row) {
      $sport_nice = $row[0]['sport_nice'];
      $team1 = $row[0]['teams'][0];
      $team2 = $row[0]['teams'][1];
      $commence_time = $row[0]['commence_time'];
      $home_team = $row[0]['home_team'];
      $site_nice = $row[0]['sites'][0]['site_nice'];
      $home = $row[0]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h'][0];
      $draw = $row[0]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h'][1];
      $away = $row[0]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h'][2];


      $sport_nice = $row[1]['sport_nice'];
        $team1 = $row[1]['teams']['0'];
        $team2 = $row[1]['teams']['1'];
        $commence_time = $row[1]['commence_time'];
        $home_team = $row[1]['home_team'];
        $site_nice = $row[1]['sites'][0]['site_nice'];
        $home = $row[1]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h']['0'];
        $draw = $row[1]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h']['1'];
        $away = $row[1]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h']['2'];

              /*foreach ($data as $row) {
              $sport_nice = $row->sport_nice;
              $team1 = $row->teams[0];
              $team2 = $row->teams[1];
              $commence_time = $row->commence_time;
              $home_team = $row->home_team;
              $site_nice = $row->sites->site_nice;
              $home = $row->sites->odds->h2h[0];
              $draw = $row->sites->odds->h2h[1];
              $away = $row->sites->odds->h2h[2];*/

        mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

## PHP(B) script

```
<?php

$filename = 'json13m.json';
$strjson = file_get_contents($filename);

$json = json_decode($strjson, true);

echo '<pre>';
var_export($json);
echo '</pre>';

$sport_nice = $json['data'][0]['sport_nice'];
$teamsA = $json['data'][0]['teams'][0];
$teamsB = $json['data'][0]['teams'][1];
$home = $json['data'][0]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h'][0];
$draw = $json['data'][0]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h'][1];
$away = $json['data'][0]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h'][2];
$sport_nice1 = $json['data'][1]['sport_nice'];
$teamsA1 = $json['data'][1]['teams'][0];
$teamsB1 = $json['data'][1]['teams'][1];
$home1 = $json['data'][1]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h'][0];
$draw1 = $json['data'][1]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h'][1];
$away1 = $json['data'][1]['sites'][0]['odds']['h2h'][2];
echo $sport_nice .'<br/>'. $teamsA .'<br/>'. $teamsB .'<br/>'. $home .'<br/>'. $draw .'<br/>'. $away;
echo '<p>------------------</p>';
echo $sport_nice1 .'<br/>'. $teamsA1 .'<br/>'. $teamsB1 .'<br/>'. $home1 .'<br/>'. $draw1 .'<br/>'. $away1;

?>
```

Comment: Which data do you actually want to loop over here? Right now, with `foreach ($data as $row)`, you are looping over the items `success` and `data`, which seems to make rather little sense. And using a numeric row index inside the foreach loop makes even less sense.

Comment: i want to parse all the 13 arrays into the MySQL DB selecting the desired objects uniformly... i know it doesn't make sense the way i am coding it... but i cant work out how to loop it thru the 13 arrays... if i do this **$sport_nice = $row['success']['sport_nice'];** i get this... **Notice: Undefined index: success in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainsite\jsontest10.php on line 19** which i thought was the logical loop thru... so if i add [0] instead of ['success'] i get the data in the DB but only the "0" array... so at the moment i am stuck.

Comment: `success` isn’t the data you want to loop over to begin with, that isn’t even an array or object, but only a scalar value (true in this particular case). The data you want to loop over is inside the array with the `data` key, so you should start by looping over `$data['data']` - then you have access to the individual objects (converted to arrays as well, due to second parameter of json_decode) in that array inside your loop. If you are not sure what structure you are dealing with then inside your loop, use var_dump for debug outputs to see what you are actually dealing with.

Comment: I have tried the `$sport_nice = $row['data']['sport_nice'];` but get `Notice: Undefined index: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainsite\jsontest10.php on line 19`

Comment: I said you should _loop over_ this, not try to access it _inside_ your loop - `foreach($data['data'] as $row)`. And again, do a var_dump inside of that loop, if you are not sure what exactly `$row` is now.